# Import and rbind multiple csv files with common name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have multiple CSV files with 4 common character in their names.
I want to know how I can rbind the files with the same common character. For example, "AM-25" is common in name of 3 csv files and "BA-35" in the name of another 2.

The files are like this
AM-25.myfiles.2000.csv, AM-25.myfiles.2001.csv ,AM-25.myfiles.2002.csv,BA-35.myfiles.2000.csv,
BA-35.myfiles.2001.csv,
I use this to read in all the files:

```
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="xyz+.csv", all.files = FALSE,full.names=TRUE )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you look for something like this?

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path=".", pattern="AM-25"), read.table, header=TRUE, sep=","))
```

This would rbind together the matrices read from your csv files which contain the characters "AM-25".
The arguments for `read.table` could be different, depending on your csv files.

---

**EDIT**

I hope this works for the case that you do not know all possible five-letter prefixes of filenames in your directory:

```
##Get all different first five letter strings for all cvs files in directory "."                                                                                                                                                                                           
file.prefixes <- unique(sapply(list.files(path=".", pattern="*.csv"), substr, 1,5))

##Group all matching file names according to file.prefixes into a list                                                                                                                                                                                                     
file.list <- lapply(file.prefixes, function(x)list.files(pattern=paste("^",x,".*.csv",sep=""), path="."))
names(file.list) <- file.prefixes ##just for convenience                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

##parse all csv files in file.list, create a list of lists containing all tables for each prefix                                                                                                                                                                           
tables <- lapply(file.list, function(filenames)lapply(filenames, function(file)read.table(file, header=TRUE)))

##for each prefix, rbind the tables. Result is a list of length being length(file.prefixes)                                                                                                                                                                                
##  each containing a matrix with the combined data parsed from the files that match the prefix                                                                                                                                                                            
joined.tables <- lapply(tables, function(t)do.call(rbind, t))

##Save tables to files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
for (prefix in names(joined.tables))write.table(joined.tables[[prefix]], paste(prefix, ".csv", sep=""))
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but is there any way that I can use the fist 5 character in the files name in the "pattern" section? I have multiple csv files and I can not provide any specific term in "pattern" section.

Comment: Do you mean that filenames which contain for example the substring "AM-25" **not** at the beginning are not matched? list.files(path=".", pattern="^AM-25") would match the files "AM-25.myfiles.2000.csv" "AM-25.myfiles.2001.csv" and "AM-25.myfiles.2002.csv" but not the file "otherfile_AM-25.myfiles.2000.csv". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with several csv files with this format so that I'm looking for way to rbind all the files that have common character in their names. like the one that you suggested with"AM-25". But these are so many files that I can't provide the "pattern" argument manually.

Comment: To be more clear I need something to search the first 5 elements of strings in a list and rbind the matched ones.

Comment: OK, I think I understand you problem better now, I did not understand that you do not know the common characters yet. I edited the answer, does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks that works! but can I save these rbinded files into new csv files with the five letter strings as their name?

Comment: See edited answer, this should work. I don;t know, however, how your csv files look like, so you maybe have to adjust the arguments for write.table (and read.table). Just look at ?write.table and ?read.table .