# Combine csv files with common file identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have a list of approximately 500 csv files each with a filename that consists of a six-digit number followed by a year (ex. 123456_2015.csv). I would like to append all files together that have the same six-digit number. I tried to implement the code suggested in this question: 
[Import and rbind multiple csv files with common name in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527720/import-and-rbind-multiple-csv-files-with-common-name-in-r) but I want the appended data to be saved as new csv files in the same directory as the original files are currently saved. I have also tried to implement the below code however the csv files produced from this contain no data.

```
rm(list=ls())

filenames <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/smithma/Desktop/PM25_test")

NAPS_ID <- gsub('.+?\\([0-9]{5,6}?)\\_.+?$', '\\1', filenames)
Unique_NAPS_ID <- unique(NAPS_ID)
n <- length(Unique_NAPS_ID)

for(j in 1:n){
      curr_NAPS_ID <- as.character(Unique_NAPS_ID[j])
      NAPS_ID_pattern <- paste(".+?\\_(", curr_NAPS_ID,"+?)\\_.+?$", sep = "" )
      NAPS_filenames <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/smithma/Desktop/PM25_test", pattern = NAPS_ID_pattern)
      write.csv(do.call("rbind",  lapply(NAPS_filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)),file = paste("C:/Users/smithma/Desktop/PM25_test/MERGED", "MERGED_", Unique_NAPS_ID[j], ".csv", sep = ""), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not doing any data manipulation, you don't need to treat the files like tabular data. You only need to copy the file contents.

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/smithma/Desktop/PM25_test", full.names = TRUE)

NAPS_ID <- substr(basename(filenames), 1, 6)
Unique_NAPS_ID <- unique(NAPS_ID)

for(curr_NAPS_ID in Unique_NAPS_ID){
  NAPS_filenames <- filenames[startsWith(basename(filenames), curr_NAPS_ID)]
  output_file <- paste0(
    "C:/Users/nwerth/Desktop/PM25_test/MERGED_", curr_NAPS_ID, ".csv"
  )
  for (fname in NAPS_filenames) {
    line_text <- readLines(fname)
    # Write the header from the first file
    if (fname == NAPS_filenames[1]) {
      cat(line_text[1], '\n', sep = '', file = output_file)
    }
    # Append every line in the file except the header
    line_text <- line_text[-1]
    cat(line_text, file = output_file, sep = '\n', append = TRUE)
  }
}
```

My changes:

- `list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)` is usually the best way to go.
- Because the digits appear at the start of the filenames, I suggest `substr`. It's easier to get an idea of what's going on when skimming the code.
- Instead of looping over the indices of a vector, loop over the values. It's more succinct and less likely to cause problems if the vector's empty.
- `startsWith` and `endsWith` are relatively new functions, and they're great.
- You only care about copying lines, so just use `readLines` to get them in and `cat` to get them out.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like this:

```
##will take the first 6 characters of each file name
six.digit.filenames <- substr(filenames, 1,6)
path <- "C:/Users/smithma/Desktop/PM25_test/"
unique.numbers <- unique(six.digit.filenames)

for(j in unique.numbers){
  sub <- filenames[which(substr(filenames,1,6) == j)]
  data.for.output <- c()
        for(file in sub){
          ##now do your stuff with these files including read them in
          data <- read.csv(paste0(path,file))
          data.for.output <- rbind(data.for.output,data)
        }
  write.csv(data.for.output,paste0(path,j, '.csv'), row.names = F)
}
```